# Moment at the end of the shaft, after a bearing?

Tags: solid-mechanics, bearings, shafts

I have an application with an interchangeable load. That can be swapped in a machine.
The bearing and break are both mounted to different sides of the same plate

The load is placed on two shafts that push into the load and are fixed/attached to the load.

The shaft then sticks outside of the bearing face by 50 mm, I need to attach this shaft to a break that has a restriction on the moment load that it can be exposed to. I cant seem to understand how much of the actual load will be seen by the shaft at the end.

- Is it half the entire load of the cantilever weight?
- Does this depend on the fit of the shaft to the bearing? Will a slip fit allow the shaft to deflect causing the moment to build up?
- Is the moment at the end based mainly on the weight of the shaft?

[image]

Comment: do you mean a brake?  The end of the shaft past the bearing is completely unstressed.